# Is $n^3$ Bounded for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ as ${n\to\infty}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is $n^3$ Bounded for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ as ${n\to\infty}$ ?

I am wondering if this is the case because I am thinking it bounded below by 1 but my textbook says its unbounded. Can someone explain why?

Comment: Think of "bounded" as meaning "contained in some fixed interval", or, in higher dimensions, "contained in some fixed ball".

Answer (score 2):

There are three notions at play here for sequences of real numbers:

- Bounded below: a sequence $u_n$ is said to be bounded below if there exists a number $A$ such that $u_n \geq A$ for all $n$;
- Bounded above: a sequence $u_n$ is said to be bounded above if there exists a number $B$ such that $u_n \leq B$ for all $n$;
- Bounded (without qualifiers): the combination of the two, ie. there exist numbers $A,B$ $A \le u_n \le B$ for all $n$.

In particular, bounded implies bounded above, but the converse is not true. In your case, the number $A = 1$ exists ($n^3 \ge 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$) but the number $B$ doesn't exist. So the sequence is not bounded, that is it is unbounded.

Comment: thank you for your help, understand it now